# Topographic Wetness Index, Raster Calculator Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I'm having issue calculating TWI, my projected coordinate system is **NAD_1983_UTM_ZONE_17N.** As I'm in Ohio, USA so I'm using this coordinate system. I have calculated the FA, FD and Slope but when ever I try to calculate TWI from these values using raster calculator, it shows an error. My other values are:

```
Columns and Rows: 1408, 1188
Number of Bands: 1
Cell Size (X, Y): 1, 1
Uncompressed Size: 6.38 MB
Format: FGDBR
Source Type: Generic 
Pixel type: floating point
Pixel Depth: 32 bit
Pyramids: Level:3, resampling: Nearest Neighbor
```

Note: Attached is the images also.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What is the error message that you are seeing?

Comment: Also, what is the equation you are using in the Raster Calculator?